# What previous works was Star Wars influenced by?

Tags: star-wars

George Lucas' epic space opera *Star Wars* was released theatrically on May 25, 1977. It became a financial triumph (by earning a total of $775 million and becoming the third highest-grossing film, when adjusted for inflation) and a critical success (by receiving ten Oscar nominations, including Best Picture, and winning seven).

I assume that George Lucas was influenced by previous movies/books. Can you name where some of those exact inspirations have originated from?

Comment: Real life or just fiction because Star wars has much influence from so many other things.

Comment: @CBredlow I meant fiction. I was wondering if there is a list of all of Star Wars' inspirations.

Comment: @CBredlow I changed the emphasis of the question, because I realized that Star Wars was probably influenced from many things. Now, what exactly are those things?

Comment: Lucas has often acknowledged that Frank Herbert's "Dune" was an inspiration and you can discover many similarities.

Answer (score 3):

Kurosawa's [Hidden Fortress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hidden_Fortress) is a well known influence.

Lucas has mentioned it numerous times.  I recall it was the inspiration for Leah.

Comment: And Flash Gordon,  Lucas had tried to secure the rights and wrote Star Wars when he was unable to.

Answer (score 2):

The final attack sequence on the Death Star has some striking resemblances to the film '633 Squadron'. 
The film ends with an attack by Mosquito fighter bombers on a German controlled plant in  Norway manufacturing heavy water needed for atomic bomb experiments. This requires them to fly along a fjord at a low level very fast and hit a precise area to destroy the plant. They come under attack from both AA guns along the fjord walls and German fighters.

Comment: Dambusters might be a similar influence; same type of mission, requiring a precision drop [though using spotlights rather than the Force ;) 9 years older than 633 Squadron, too.

Comment: Dambusters was inspired by the real Operation Chatise, to drop the Upkeep mine. It lacks the element of an attack down a narrow fjord or trench under heavy fire and fighter attack that both '633 Squadron' and 'Star Wars' have.  Although it probably did have an influence I agree.

Answer (score -1):

Akira Kurosawa's Hidden Fortress was a major influence on Star Wars, it could be argued that Star Wars IS a science fiction remake of Hidden Fortress.

I read a magazine dedicated to this subject years ago. Originally George Lucas wanted to make a Flash Gordon film but was unable to secure the rights, so he invented his own "Original" universe utilising all his influences: Flash Gordon, Buck Rogers, Samurai Films, Westerns, Pirate films, World War II films. Science fiction literature: The Foundation series by Isaac Asimov, Dune by Frank Herbert, Lord of the Rings. Lucas was quite open about it and you can see all these influences in the films.